# Factorial induction proof with recursion, no idea where to go

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

So I've been stuck on this one problem from my Foundations of Computing class where I'm given a function $T(n)$ and the base cases are defined already and a function is given to find the other $n$ values greater than the base case. This is how it looks.

> Consider the following recursively defined function:
>
> $$T(n)=\begin{cases}
> 3,&\text{if }n=1\\
> 6,&\text{if }n=2\\
> 18,&\text{if }n=3\\
> T(n-3)(n^3-3n^2+2n),&\text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Use induction to prove that $T(n)=3(n!)$ for all $n\ge 1$.

I have no clue how to even get started on this. We never covered factorial induction proofs, let alone with recursion in my class so I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try factorizing the cubic factor. Then prove by induction that$$T(n)=n!3,\,T(n+1)=(n+1)!3,\,T(n+2)=(n+2)!3.$$

Comment: All you have to do is to confirm that $3\times n!$ satisfies the same recursion and the same initial conditions as $T(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing special about the fact that a factorial is involved. It’s immediate from the definition of $T$ that $T(n)=3n!$ for $n=1,2,3$; those are your base cases for this strong induction. For the induction step you simply have to use the definition of $T$ to show that if $T(k)=3k!$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$, where $n>3$, then $T(n)=3n!$. That definition says that

$$T(n)=T(n-3)(n^3-3n^2+2n)\,,$$

so your task is to use the induction hypothesis and a little algebra to show that the righthand side simplifies to $3n!$. HINT: It will be helpful to factor $n^3-3n^2+2n$.

Comment: I understand everything you said above but the 3 in front of n! is messing up my proof.

3n! = (n)(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3) for n > 3

This works if that 3 isn't there, or am I not thinking about this the correct way?

Comment: @Raz-AlPool: What are you substituting for $T(n-3)$?

Comment: Wouldn't the (n - 3) just be added on to the factor of n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n
The factor is n(n-1)(n-2) so would it become n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)?

I'm still a bit confused as to what I'm supposed to be substituting in the inductive step.

Comment: @Raz-AlPool: There is no factor of $n-3$: there is a factor of $T(n-3)$. The induction hypothesis says that $T(k)=3k!$ if $1\le k<n$, and we know that $1\le n-3<n$, so what is $T(n-3)$?

Comment: Would that just be 3(n - 3)!

Comment: @Raz-AlPool: It would indeed. Now just combine that with your $n(n-1)(n-2)$, and you should be all set.

Comment: I actually got it! n! will include (n - 3)! because n! > (n-3)!

Comment: @Raz-AlPool: Yep, that’s exactly what happens. The factor $n^3-3n^2+2n$ is simply designed to push $(n-3)!$ up to $n!$.

Comment: One last thing, why do we input (n - 3) into T(n) = 3(n!) and not into the recursive function T(n) = T(n - 3)(n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n)?

Since n, in this case, is > 3, it satisfies the condition "otherwise"

Comment: @Raz-AlPool: We’re using the *otherwise* condition to write $$T(n)=T(n-3)(n^3-3n^2+2n)\,;$$ we then use the induction hypothesis to rewrite $T(n-3)$ as $3(n-3)!$ and do a little algebra to conclude that $T(n)=3n!$, which is what we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is coming in late and you've accepted an answer already, but I thought I would provide a proof of the claim $T(n) = 3n!$ with $T(n)$ the recurrence relation you provided. We prove the claim using induction.

First we consider the base cases $n \in \{1, 2, 3\}$:

$T(1) = 3 \cdot 1! = 3$

$T(2) = 3 \cdot 2! = 6$

$T(3) = 3 \cdot 3! = 18$

And so the base cases hold. Now we consider $n > 3$:

$T(n) = 3n! = T(n - 3) \cdot n \cdot \left( n^2 - 3n + 2 \right)$

$3n! = 3(n - 3)! \cdot n \cdot (n - 1)(n - 2)$

$3n! = 3n(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3)!$

And so we may conclude that $T(n) = 3n!$ for $n > 3$. Since the three base cases hold, then by strong induction we may conclude that $T(n) = 3n!$ for all $n > 0$.